# Problems after removing gnome-shell package

Tags: unity, gnome, nautilus, gtk

I recently installed the gnome-shell package to try out gnome desktop, didn't like it so much so I removed it and returned to unity. I'm trying to fix a few things that seem to have been messed up by gnome:

**pressing Super + W crashes unity**

I ran unity from a terminal window to get the output from the crash, this is the error message:

```
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: scale
WARN  2015-08-20 16:48:39 unityo (appinfo2) <unknown>:0 g_settings_set_value: value for key 'visual-bell-type' in schema 'org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences' is outside of valid range
ERROR 2015-08-20 16:48:39 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:524 DBus name lost 'org.gnome.Shell'
ERROR 2015-08-20 16:48:39 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:524 DBus name lost 'com.canonical.Unity'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

another weird thing is that some applications now seem to be using a different version of gtk or something, nautilus now has only an x button and its on the other side, also the system monitor looks like that now.

some applications like the system settings have stayed the same.
whats going on?

Answer (score 1):

You could, from a TTY, try reinstalling the ubuntu-desktop packages.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
```

This will try to do a fresh install of the Unity environment over whatever is already there, which should fix any issues you are having.